# Google bigquery (GBQ) churn / retention rate from previous month

Tags: google-bigquery, retention, churn

I'm using google bigquery and try to understand monthly churn from the following table, e.g. 1 user (C) churned, and 1 user (D) is new.

My thought was to self join and see which user shows 'null' in current month as a churn, 'null' in previous month is new. But the query returns to "left" join result when I'm using "full join". How should I fix it? I'll be open to other approach as well! thank you!

| userid | active_month |
| --- | --- |
| A | Jan 2022 |
| B | Jan 2022 |
| D | Jan 2022 |
| A | Dec 2021 |
| B | Dec 2021 |
| C | Dec 2021 |
| A | Nov 2021 |
| B | Nov 2021 |

```
select
t1.active_month,
count(distinct t1.userid) recent_user,
count(distinct t2.userid) previous_user,
count(distinct case when t1.userid is null then t2.userid end) as churned_user,
count(distinct case when t2.user is null then t1.userid end) as new_user
from table t1
full outer join table t2
on t1.active_month = datesub(t2.active_month, interval 1 month)
and t1.userid=t2.userid
```

Answer (score 0):

The two problems I see with your query are:

- the join clause should be reversed, so subtracting 1 month from t1.active_date instead of t2.active_date
- when you select the t1.active_month you need to coalesce with t2.active_month because it's a full outer join

I have slightly changed your query and added one more condition in the calculation of churned_user to exclude the t2.userid with t2.active_month equal to the most recent active_month. Now it should be correct.

```sql
select
coalesce(t1.active_month, t2.active_month) as active_month,
count(distinct t1.userid) recent_user,
count(distinct IF(t2.userid is not null and t2.active_month is not null and t2.active_month <> (select max(active_month) from table), t2.userid, NULL)) previous_user,
count(distinct case when t1.userid is null and t2.active_month <> (select max(active_month) from table) then t2.userid end) as churned_user,
count(distinct case when t2.userid is null then t1.userid end) as new_user
from table t1
full outer join table t2
on date_sub(t1.active_month, interval 1 month) = t2.active_month and t1.userid = t2.userid
group by 1
order by 1
```

Just as an alternative approach the following would also calculate for each month:

- recent_user: as the number of active users for a month
- previous_user: as the number of active users for the previous month
- churned_user: as the number of users that were last active on a month
- new_user: as the number of users that are first seen on a month

Window functions LAG and LEAD come in handy for calculating the previous and next active month for each userid

```sql
WITH
  table AS (
  SELECT
    MAX(active_month) OVER() AS current_month,
    userid,
    active_month,
    LAG(active_month) OVER(PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY active_month) AS previous_month,
    LEAD(active_month) OVER(PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY active_month) AS next_month
  FROM
    original_table
  ORDER BY
    userid,
    active_month)
SELECT
  active_month,
  COUNT(userid) AS recent_user,
  COUNTIF(DATE_DIFF(active_month, previous_month, MONTH) = 1) AS previous_user,
  COUNTIF(next_month IS NULL AND active_month <> current_month) AS churned_user,
  COUNTIF(previous_month IS NULL) AS new_user
FROM
  TABLE
GROUP BY
  active_month
ORDER BY
  active_month
```

Comment: Hi C.Georgiadis, thank you sooo much for helping!

Comment: Hi C.Georgiadis I have tried the first one, but got the result that recent_user and previous_user return exactly same result. e.g. recent_user:100, previous_user:100....seems like

Comment: And I'm also trying the the second one, new parts looks perfect!! thank you so much! as 'churn' still looks off, I think it shud because my 'churn' definition is the users who active in the previous month but not active in current month

Comment: I've edited the first query @Lunana, so now previous_user should be calculated correctly

Comment: By the way if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.